# 90's early 2000 movie about students kidnapping their teacher

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller

I'm trying to identify a movie, hope that I can help you help me.

The plot revolves around some highschool mature looking kids (a group that includes both girls and boys) who kidnap their teacher cause he was very mean to them to try to teach him a lesson and soften him up. They take the teacher to a house far away from town blindfolded and he doesn't know who has kidnapped him or where he is, they got him tied to a chair and speak to him with a voice modulator.

I recall that the voice modulator breaks when one girl is talking to him and he recognizes her voice, the teacher starts to freak out and threaten her, turns out the teacher had to take heart pills and with this episode of rage he has a heart attack and needs the pills, but the "boss" of the kids doesn't believe him and starts punching him until the teacher dies and now they got a real problem.

That's all I can remember, some info that could help identify the movie:

- Year: Late 90's, maybe early 2000's
- Language: English
- Country: USA

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [Killing Mr. Griffin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119461/combined) with Amy Jo Johnson, Mario Lopez and Michelle Williams from 1997:

> Mr. Griffin (Jay Thomas) is a bitter high-school teacher, who pushes his students to the limit and is hated by most of them. When he humiliates the popular student Mark Kinney (Scott Bairstow) is his class, Mark convinces his friends to play a prank on Mr. Griffin. The group manipulates Susan McConnell (Amy Jo Johnson), using her to attract the teacher to the parking area after hours. They kidnap, blindfold and take him to an abandoned boat house nearby a lake, and trying to frighten him, they leave him tied on a chair alone in the desert place without his heart pills. Mr. Griffin dies and when his body is found, the group panics.

They use a voice scrambler but it breaks. The film was based on a Young Adult novel [by the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_Mr._Griffin). Here's the trailer:

Comment: Yes!, this is exactly the movie, thanks a lot Walt. I'm new here so i can't vote up but at least i can accept the answer :). I wanted to watch it couse i've never seen the end.

Comment: Holy crap! I didn't know they made a film of this. It was one of my favorite books in junior high.

Comment: yeah the other day i catched a little bit of that movie on cable but i had to go and i couldn't continue watching, luckily internet is full of awesome people who are willing to lend a hand!. P.S: I could vote up the answer, very much deserved sir!. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem. And if you want a movie with the same theme, there's [Teaching Mrs. Tingle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_Mrs._Tingle).